# "*." is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: anaconda, operating-system, command-prompt

As soon as I open my Anaconda prompt, I see this error message [image: please refer this]
"*." is not recognized as an internal or external command. I didn't even type anything in the prompt I still get this message anyway and I could not activate any environment as well.

Comment: Were any initialization scripts modified recently? If there's an Anaconda config file that's loaded every time the prompt is started, there might be an error in there.

Comment: no script is modified but this started as soon as I updated software in my laptop

Comment: You might have to reinstall anaconda or update it. :\